# Joomla ignores css changes after URL rewrite was activated

Tags: templates, css, joomla-4.x, cassiopeia

I recently installed Joomla 4.1 on my server and since I activated URL rewriting, my changes in some CSS files of the Cassiopeia Template are ignored.

I tried deactivating the URL Rewrite, but it does not change this behavior. Maybe it was just coincidence that the changes got ignored after I activated this feature.

Answer (score 0):

In Cassiopeia, you must add the custom css into the `user.css`, and place this file in `templates/cassiopeia/css/user.css` (for Joomla 4.0) or in `media/templates/site/cassiopeia/css/user.css` (for Joomla 4.1)